# Dereferencing structure instance element using structure instance pointer

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I have this function:

```c
static pair_t * // not visible outside this file
pair_new(const int key)
{

  pair_t *pair = malloc(sizeof(pair_t));

  if (pair == NULL) {
    // error allocating memory for pair; return error
    return NULL;
  } else {


            printf("key is %d\n",key);

      *(pair->key) = key;
      *(pair->count) = 1;
      pair->next = NULL;
      return pair;

  }
}
```

but the way I am trying to dereference the key element of the instance of pair is giving me a seg fault. I think it is because 'pair' is a pointer.

the pair structure is defined as follows:

```c
typedef struct pair {
  int *key;                // search key for this item
  int *count;                  // pointer to data for this item
  struct pair *next;   // children
} pair_t;
```

Any suggestions on how to properly change the value of `key` would be much appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there's no issue with `pair`, it's with `key` (and the `count`, too). The pointer is used uninitialized which invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

At the point where you;re trying to dereference `key`

```
 *(pair->key) = key;
```

there's no valid memory allocated to `key`, so the dereference invokes UB. You need to allocate memory to `key` before you can use it. same goes for the `count`, too.

Comment: thanks, i added :
pair->key = malloc(sizeof(int));
pair->count = malloc(sizeof(int));

and it seems to work now

Comment: @dirtyb You're welcome. You can also [consider accepting an answer that helped you](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/244062).